# Typescript changes visibility of types depending on the content of the file

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I have a simple `types.ts` file:

```
interface Foo {
  test: string;
}
```

Now I can use this Foo overall in all files without importing and it compiles just fine. When I add e.g. import to the top of the file then it suddenly stops being "visible" and needs to be imported.

```
import { Bar } from 'Bar';

interface Foo {
  test: string;
}
```

I don't really understand this behaviour and cannot find documentation on this. Does typescript treat files that have only type definitions as .d.ts file or something?

Is it even a good idea to have these file in your own code (not a library) or it's better to explicitly export/import all the types?

Comment: Can't find proper docs on this, but there's no special treatment for `*.d.ts` files. The difference is between global(non module) file and module file (has import or export or both). Here you can find some declaration files templates https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/templates.html. Hope this helps

Comment: Will take a look, thanks. It is strange though there is no documentation on such an important topic

Comment: It is there, did not properly understand it until you wrote it out for me :) In TypeScript, just as in ECMAScript 2015, any file containing a top-level import or export is considered a module. Conversely, a file without any top-level import or export declarations is treated as a script whose contents are available in the global scope (and therefore to modules as well). You can post it as an answer if you want to

Answer (score 2):

Have found the answer in the official documentation:

> In TypeScript, just as in ECMAScript 2015, any file containing a
>   top-level import or export is considered a module. Conversely, a file
>   without any top-level import or export declarations is treated as a
>   script whose contents are available in the global scope (and therefore
>   to modules as well).